# Problem with linear regression normal equations when a coefficient should be zero

Tags: regression

I am having trouble using the linear regression normal equations to minimize a function of several variables. The minimization solution is :

$$\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$$
where $\beta$ is the coefficient vector of a function to minimize :
$$f(x,y)=\beta_1g_1(k_1,x_1,y_1)...\beta_ng_n(k_n,x_1,y_1)$$
$g$ is a function of $k,A \text{ and } B$.

The $k$'s are parameters that I set manually.

$x_i$ and $y_i$ are $i$ measurements taken at points $i\in {1,...,m}$

and 
The matrix $X$ is

$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
    g_1(k_1,x_1,y_1)       & \dots     & g_n(k_n,x_1,y_1) \\
    \vdots                &           & \vdots          \\
    g_1(k_1,x_m,y_m)       & \dots     & g_n(k_n,x_m,y_m)
\end{bmatrix}$$
and $Y=[Y_{true}(x_1,y_1),...Y_{true}(x_m,y_m)]$, which is a vector of true experimental results at m measurements.

This all works nicely, except when one of the $K=0$. Ideally if I set one of the $K=0$, the corresponding $\beta$ should also equal zero. Instead, setting a $K$ to zero ends up making all of the $\beta$ coefficients equal to zero. Why is this, and is there a work around?

Comment: The formula $\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ only works when $X$ has full column rank. When this is not the case, you need to use pseudo inverses. Serge Lang in his book "Linear Models" has a beautiful chapter on pseudo inverses and the book deals with the general case when $X^TX$ is singular.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked at Serge Lang's list of books but can't find "Linear Models." Do you have a link where I can find out more about the book?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serge_Lang#List_of_books

Comment: According to your $f$, that is $f(x,y) = \prod_{i=1}^n \beta_i g_i(k_i, x_i, y_i)$, hence if $\beta_k=0$ then $f$ becomes $0$.

Comment: @Frank - Sorry, I'm getting old.The book is from [Searle](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118491782)